# Variable as an html file how to grep tag

Tags: php, html, ssh

I written the following code:

```
<?php



include('C:\Manutenzione\Analisi_TT\simple_html_dom.php');

$ip_soatt04='myip';

$usr_soatt = 'root';
$pwd_soatt = 'mypwd';
$tag = 'li class="server"';

$connection_soatt04 = ssh2_connect($ip_soatt04, 22);

if (!$connection_soatt04)
{
    echo "impossibile connettersi a soatt04";
}
    
ssh2_auth_password($connection_soatt04, $usr_soatt , $pwd_soatt);

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection_soatt04,'cat /opt/sw/db_viewer/todata_summary.html');

stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

$stream_out=stream_get_contents($stream);
//$stream_out=file_get_html($stream,true);

foreach($stream_out->find($tag) as $server){
    $server_array[] = trim($server->innertext);
}?>
```

But I get as output:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\Manutenzione\Analisi_TT\script_TT.php on line 27
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\Manutenzione\Analisi_TT\script_TT.php on line 27

Why this?
I thought that $stream_out isn't an object, but how to make it an object?

Comment: [stream_get_contents](https://www.php.net/stream_get_contents) _"Returns a string or false on failure"_. Why should `$stream_out->find($tag)` work then, any more than `$stream_out->do_stuff_i_need('magically')`? It returns a string, if you want the lines separate to loop over, then e.g. `preg_split('~\v+~', $that_string)`, and if you want an object with that data, then instantiate an appropriate class for that task. Also, what is `$tag` and where does it come from? Or `$server->innertext`? Not defined in your code.